# Help creating assets for iOS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile, ios

I´m new creating assets for iOS. I only did UI until now. I´m a bit confused creating assets ini photoshop. Anyone can let me know the image size in pixels for 1x, 2x and 3x? I´m wrong whit these? 1x= 320x480px 2x= 640x1136px (5&5s), 750x1334px (6) 3x= 1242x2208px (6+)

When I try to create assets, I start from a psd size 1242x2208 and try to create the 2x and 1x from that, but the size in pixels are weird...I started with the bigger size because I´m using pictures on my PSD, not only shapes and smart objects.

What I´m doing wrong? :(

Thanks!!

Comment: [First of all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sgfc4.gif). Secondly, what do you mean the size is weird? In your second paragraph you are saying that you're starting from the largest size and saving 2x and 1x versions? Well 2x makes it two times bigger and 1x doesn't change the size at all.  I'm not getting the question.

Comment: First of all: LOL!!! I love Seinfeld!!!
Second: I start from a PSD that is 1242x2208pixels, I´m using images on an app tutorial, so I can´t start from a size smaller than 3x.
When I export to 2x and 1x, it exports at weird sizes, I mean, at 2x it expots at 414x736pixels, and the 2x at 828x1472pixels.

Comment: I know that 1232 is 3x 414, but I dont know how to deal with this, because I´m using images and I can´t start from 1x (that would be easy!) Right now, I created one psd file for each device size (1242, 750, 640, 320) and I´m exporting without scale. But it is a lot of work! Maybe an experienced designer in exporting assets can help me to use a simple way... Thanks!!! (sorry for my basic english :()

Comment: One solution might be to use the assets generator in Photoshop CC, [which allows you to define the output size with percentages](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Web-Assets-Functional-Spec). So since you can't do like -2x, you'd do 50%. Although, it might be easier just to convert the raster images to smart objects, then downsize and export normally.

Comment: Thank you Jonas! I found the answer to my question, I hope that it helps another designer with the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, just if another designer have the same doubt than me: If you have pictures, and you have the 3x resolution, just create smart object of your pictures. Then you can resize to 320px of width. Then you can use PNGExpress or another kind of soft, to export it at 100%, 200% and 300%. And it is done! The ppi of each device will make it fit porportionately. (remember that 401 is less than 163ppi*3). I hope this help to another that have the same question!!! –

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it the correct answer so it doesn't remain in our list of "Unanswered" questions. You'll also receive a little rep for it.